# How to stop foreach loop when fetch is failed?

Tags: javascript, foreach, fetch-api

I have a function:

```
function check(id) {
    let index = 0
    fetch('https://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/api/versions.json')
    .then(e => e.json())
    .then((res) =>res.forEach( element =>{
        fetch('https://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/'+element+'/img/profileicon/'+id+'.png')
        .then(response => {
            if(response.ok){
                index++
            }
            else{
                return index
            }
        })
    }))
}
```

The code seems to be dirty and not right, sorry for that.

I am getting an array of numbers and at line 6, I check if the website is legit. After some index, invalid URLs will start. I want to break foreach loop when an invalid URL tried to fetch. I tried to convert 'foreach' loop to a 'some' loop and tried some try-catch blocks but I couldn't break the loop.
[If you want to see how it stacks when invalid URLs start to stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgglG.png)

Comment: Easiest is to switch to async/await and a regular `for` loop so you can use `break`.

Comment: What if you have valid urls after the invalid one - are you just ignoring them?

Comment: @Andy i basically count how many of them passed. And i am sure that no valid url will come after an invalid one. Because it lined up for release date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to count how many requests were fulfilled/rejected you may find [`Promise.allSettled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) useful. Add your endpoints to an array, [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the array to create an array of promises, and then [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Promises#async_and_await) all the promises to resolve/reject. You can then inspect the result to see how many requests have a status that is either "fulfilled" or "rejected".

```js
const arr = [
  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1',
  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/2',
  'https://madeup.url.com/todos',
  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/4',
  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/4'
];

// `map` over the array of endpoints and
// return an array of promises
function getPromises(arr) {
 return arr.map(url => {
    return fetch(url)
      .then(res => {
        if (res.ok) return res.json();
      })
      .catch(err => {
        return Promise.reject('Request failed');
      });
  });
}

// Return the count of objects
// with a particular status
function count(data, status) {
  return data.filter(obj => obj.status === status).length;
}

// Create an array of promises, `await` the result, and
// then find out how many were "fulfilled" or "rejected
async function main(arr) {
  const promises = getPromises(arr);
  const data = await Promise.allSettled(promises);
  const fulfilled = count(data, 'fulfilled');
  const rejected = count(data, 'rejected');
  console.log(`Fulfilled: ${fulfilled}\nRejected: ${rejected}`);
}

main(arr);
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort. It seems like work for me. Also at your first review, it did not work for me.